# Sort files in Total-Commander by modification status (SVN)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, total-commander

I am using Total Commander with the SVN Plugin (Tortoise SVN installed on Windows) to display overlay icons and toolbar functionality.

I was wondering if there is a command or something else, that allows me to sort the files by their modification status: modified, not modified.

For example an extra column, next to creation date, file size, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure user defined columns and add the desired TortoiseSVN fields with [SVNDetails](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svndetails/) plugin.

Comment: Any Idea on how to display additional column(having user defined property for revision) in svn log window of tortoise svn ?